# What will happen to a hybrid cordova project if a Google API key (mentioned in index.html) is dead?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, google-places-api

I have a hybrid Cordova project written in HTML, CSS, JS, Angularjs. The Google Places API key of the project has expired? What will happen, will the project crash?

I am not using that particular Google Places API key right now, but I have still the reference of that Google API Key URL in the index.html file. Will the app crash if the reference is kept intact?

Comment: DL your app and try it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app won't crash, but API calls to Google Places will fail.